# Popup using useState stopped working in React 18

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-18

I made a popup using `useState` which worked in React 17 but stopped in React 18 without any errors being displayed.

When I set the `isVisible` state to be `true` initially the Popup gets displayed but setting it to using the button does not work.

I'm wondering why this is the case and how I can migrate it to React 18 since I need it for other dependencies in my project.

```
{isVisible && (
  <Popup
    visible={isVisible}
    toggle={() => {
      setLightboxVisible(false);
      document.body.classList.toggle("body-noscroll-class");
    }}
  >
    Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </Popup>
)}

<button 
  onClick={() => {
    setLightboxVisible(true);
  }}>
Show Popup
</button>
```

Here is a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-joana-gbispc?file=/src/App.js) which shows the behavior.

Comment: Inside `Popup` the `useOuterClick` it's firing to early, on the first render it's just called and hides the popup. Take a look into defined hook and how you can avoid this call on first render.

Comment: @Miłosz Ohh I see, that makes sense but why did it work in React 17?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea, looking on this still and I can't find the solution for now. At least we know it's this 

Comment: Alexander, I've changed the event from `click` to `mousedown` and it works.

Comment: @Miłosz that is very strange, the problem with `mousedown` is that it only stays visible for as long as the mouse is down and as soon as I release it, it disappears again.

Comment: Not in the button handler but in the hook: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-cdn-vjih7v?file=/src/hooks.js

Comment: @AlexanderHörl, if I may, I would say that for a popup your code is much complexe. There is a raison it should be this way?

Comment: @Miłosz Oh thats great, you may post that as an answer.

Comment: @yousoumar Yeah I've also thought that its quite complex, do you have a better solution tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing `click` to `mousedown` in the `useOuterClick` hook, as suggested by @Miłosz

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-cdn-vjih7v?file=/src/hooks.js

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use css display to show or hide elements in react. Just use react code to either render it to the DOM or don't render it to the DOM. You were already doing this in app.js, and then in your popup you were doing it again. So in the css you didn't need the display property. See simplified version in the new codesandbox.

Use useEffect to listen for changes to isVisible to determine when to toggle the css class on the body.

Add an onClick to the modal backdrop, but then on the inner div prevent the click event from bubbling up to the parent by using e.stopPropagation.

See these changes in the updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-ganguly-16c21x?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Really good point you're making here. It's always nice to see it not mixing React and vanilla. Did you consider portal to achieve modal which is detached from the nested html?

Comment: The problem here is that by default the `body-noscroll-class` is activated.