# Bug with click event in react-18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-18

The react version I'm using is:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
```

Here's some simple code for the dropdown.

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-firefly-sphup6?file=/src/App.tsx

```js
import { MouseEvent, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';

type DropdownProps = {
  target: HTMLElement | null;
  children: ReactNode;
};

function Dropdown({ target, children }: DropdownProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!target) return;

    const listener = () => {
      console.log('listener executed');
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', listener);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('click', listener);
  }, [target]);

  if (!target) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div>{children}</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [target, setTarget] = useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={(e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) =>
          setTarget(e.currentTarget)
        }
      >
        Button
      </button>
      <Dropdown target={target}>dropdown test</Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here, when the button is pressed for the first time, an event is attached to the document and the listener is executed immediately.

[The result of the first button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOscp.png)

The behavior I expect is that the first time the button is pressed, the event is attached to the document, and the next time the button is pressed, the listener fires.

In practice, however, the event listener fires as soon as the button is first pressed.

This was a problem that did not occur when using ReactDom.render of React 17, but a problem occurs while using createRoot of 18.

It seems to be a similar issue to the one in the link below

[Popup using useState stopped working in React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72485865/popup-using-usestate-stopped-working-in-react-18)

I want to know why this doesn't work in react 18.

Comment: Could be because of strict mode. Does it also do the same in production?

Comment: Yes it happens the same in production mode but not in strict mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of the new concurrent rendering mechanism of React.

I managed to fix this using useDeferredValue

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-frog-clj1wi?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I also vaguely thought that it might be a related problem. Thanks for pointing out a new way to solve this. Delaying this with a setTimeout also solves the problem.